# How to export excel file as csv using macro?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I want to export the excel file as csv using macro.

But my code export only the header of each column, not the whole records that inputted in excel file and the header display on the 2nd row instead on 1st row.

How to fix this?

In additional, what if there's a new column and new records inputted in excel file. How to determine this in macro? It is possible? Thank you

Macro:

```
 Sub WriteCSVFile()

 Dim My_filenumber As Integer
 Dim logSTR As String

 My_filenumber = FreeFile

 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "A").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "B").Value & Format(Now, "yyyyMMddhhmmss") & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "C").Value & Format(Now, "yyyyMMddhhmmss") & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "D").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "E").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "F").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "G").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "H").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "I").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "J").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "K").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "L").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "M").Value

 Open "C:\Users\username\foldername\Sample.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
 Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```

Desire output:

```
 Header1, Header2,    Header3, Header4
 1234456, 10/10/2014, Marc,    24
```

Comment: Your desired output doesn't seem to match your code.  Perhaps have a look at this recent thread which may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676354/macro-for-exporting-text-files-from-excel-file-with-multiple-worksheets/26676831#26676831

Comment: @barryleajo i try that first script and I get an error, says.. "out of range" while the second script, it's always repeat the save step and when I check csv. There's no records

Comment: Yes - think of the example as a possible template which you have to modify to meet your data and requirements.  It was written for the  requirement in that question not yours.

Comment: I know, but I'm new in vb and macro. Can you help me with this, pls?

Comment: Edit your Q to show how your source data is structured and which of this data needs to be written to text file.

Answer (score 0):

I already solve the issue with this

```
 Dim DirLoc As Variant

DirLoc = "pathname"

'~~> Check if it is a valid entry
If DirLoc <> False Then
    '~~> Check before hand if the file exists
    If Not Dir(DirLoc) <> "" Then
        '~~> If not then save it
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=DirLoc
    Else
        '~~> Trap the error and ignore it
        On Error Resume Next
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else '<~~ If user press Save
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=DirLoc, _
            FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
            ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
        End If
    End If
End If
```